# Furstenberg's topology and Adele

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

It is well known that Furstenberg put a topology on $\mathbb Z$ which he uses to show the infinitude of primes. It may also be well known (see [Could Furstenberg's Argument Prove the Infinitude of Primes in Number Fields?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275312/could-furstenbergs-argument-prove-the-infinitude-of-primes-in-number-fields)) that this topology is actually the Adele topology on $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ restricted to $\mathbb Z$. My question is then a slightly historical one:

> Was Furstenberg in any way inspired by the theory of Adeles when
>   discovering his proof?

Note: No intent to discount Furstenberg's originality in his proof.

Addendum: The corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes#cite_ref-mercer_1-0) contains [this paper](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=70&iss=3&rank=3) on the Furstenberg topology which is written at a fairly elementary level. There is some construction resembling $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ but the Adeles are not mentioned explicitly.